# Javascript function returns error when I click on a <li> on codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using code behind(something.ascx.cs) to generate an un-ordered list from my database using the following code.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            htmlRender.Append("<ul>");
            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                var courseCategory = row[i-1];
                htmlRender.Append("<li id='"+ courseCategory + "' onclick='getCourseCategory(this.id)'  >");
                htmlRender.Append(row[i]);
                htmlRender.Append("</li>");                    
            }
            htmlRender.Append("</ul>");                
        }
```

But when I click on the list it gives an error "getCourseCategory" is not defined.So my problem is how do I access the "getCourseCategory" function whose definition is in something.ascx file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {        
    function getCourseCategory(courseCategoryID) {
        alert('hello');
    };
});
```

Comment: i did not undestand your question

Comment: What is the problem exactly? It doesnt get into that function?

Comment: The problem is when I click on the list, it returns an error called getCourseCategory is not defined

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answers here: [How to call javascript and C# function on HTML Button Click](http://forums.asp.net/t/1324613.aspx?How+to+call+javascript+and+C+function+on+HTML+Button+Click)

Comment: @KeyurPATEL my click event is defined at ascx.cs file not at ascx file as the example shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written function inside `document.ready` it should be outside of that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function getCourseCategory(courseCategoryID) {
    alert('hello');
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the solution, the DOM has loaded when the page is visible.  The issue is calling the javascript on the click event

Comment: @Leopard Is there a way by which I can define it inside the document.ready and still get it to work?

Comment: @BibekAryal why do you want to do this ?

Comment: @Leopard can you please start a chat room so we can discuss it there?

Comment: @BibekAryal are you allowed chat room ?

Comment: @Leopard yes i am allowed to join chat room but not allowed to create one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121917/discussion-between-leopard-and-bibek-aryal).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `this` is available when you're clicking on the list item...

```
foreach(var row in dt.Rows)
{
    htmlRender.Append("<ul>");
    for(var i = 0; i <= dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        var courseCategory = row[i];
        htmlRender.Append("<li id='"+ courseCategory + "' onclick='getCourseCategory(" + courseCategory + ")' >");
        ....
        htmlRender.Append("</li>");
    }
    htmlRender.Append("</ul>");
}
```

Comment: It seems to work fine @Matt .Checked it with  alert(courseCategoryID); and its working fine

Comment: Great! Mark my answer as the answer to your soluton

Comment: I'm sorry but my problem was that I was defining the getCourseCategory inside $document.ready as pointed out by @leopard

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the better way is to use javascript (in your case with jquery i think) to bind the click function.

ascx.cs:

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        htmlRender.Append("<ul>");
        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            var courseCategory = row[i-1];
            htmlRender.Append("<li data-id='"+ courseCategory + "'>");
            htmlRender.Append(row[i]);
            htmlRender.Append("</li>");                    
        }
        htmlRender.Append("</ul>");                
    }
```

Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function getCourseCategory(inputId) {
    console.log('Your input was: ' + inputId);
  }

  $('li').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    getCourseCategory(id);
  });
});
```

the code is not tested because i can't rebuild your ascx on my system. but i think it should work

Comment: the problem with this is, this will give me problem if I click on any other list in my page

Comment: you simply have to set id to the ul and arrange the jquery selector i.e. your id is sample the code shoult be ```$('#sample li')```